# Can code be called outside of draw() in processing, other than in setup()

Tags: processing

According to Processing's translation reference page [reference page](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html),  "If translate() is called within draw(), the transformation is reset when the loop begins again." Is there any way to call code outside of draw(), other than setup()?

I'm new to Processing, please forgive me if I've overlooked something obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside"? You can define arbitrary amount of classes and methods outside of `setup` and `draw`. But how many entry points to an application do you need, really?

Comment: I didn't mean classes outside of draw() (I realize that I worded the question ambiguously). I'm assuming that the reference page says that anything called within the draw() function will be reset on the next draw(). Can anything be called outside the draw() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple ways you can call `translate()` and other Processing functions outside of the `draw()` function.

You could use a static sketch that just draws a single frame without looping:

```
size(200, 200); 
translate(width/2, height/2); 
ellipse(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

This is a full program and will draw a circle in the center of the window.

Or you could put your drawing code inside an event function:

```
void setup(){
 size(200, 200); 
}

void draw(){
 translate(0, 100);
}

void mousePressed(){
 translate(100, 0);
 background(32);
 ellipse(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

This program draws a circle in the center of the window when the user presses the mouse. But note that the calls to `translate()` stack: the `translate(0, 100)` call in `draw()` and the `translate(100, 0)` call in `mousePressed()` are added together so the circle shows up at `100,100`. The `draw()` function is called first, and then the event functions are called.

The reference is just telling you that translation is reset the next time `draw()` is called.

Comment: Oooh, I see. So transformations in mousePressed() & other events will also be reset when draw() is called.

Answer (score 0):

No, there cannot be called something outside the draw()-function. When you want to use `translate()` with variable values, then use variables, that define the translation. When you want to translate to the same point each time, then call `translate()` with constant values at the beginning of each loop...